# IE 6 css issues with absolute positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a absolute positioned element with proper top and left. On page load the element doesn't show up but whenever I apply any css from IE Dev Toolbar it shows. Can anyone please help me finding a solution for it.
Note: I already tried giving relative position to its parent.

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup or provide us a link to the page for better understanding of the issue?

Comment: <html>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 110px; border: 1px solid red">test</div>
</body>
</html>

this works correctly

Comment: Ensure that another DOM element doesn't have a higher zIndex than your DOM element on page load. and what rochala says sounds good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure parent div has position:relative; applied - it solves the issue in 90% of cases.
It would help a lot if you put simplified HTML of your problem.